# Ruby 1.8.7 on windows with cygwin

Tags: ruby, cygwin

I am completely new to Ruby, and i am required to use ruby 1.8.7. I was able to install it on windows and when I run the 'gem' command on windows command line it works. I was also able to run hello world in ruby. Now, I need to run gem command from cygwin. I just installed cygwin with default options and ran the gem command I get.

> C:\Ruby187\bin\ruby.exe: No such file or directory --
> /cygdrive/c/Ruby187/bin/gem (LoadError)

Note that I don't want to use the Ruby that comes with cygwin because I need ruby 1.8.7

Comment: Where is gem installed? Have you checked if you have a gem.exe in `C:\Ruby187\bin\`

Comment: Yes I see a gem and a gem.bat in 'C:\Ruby187\bin' working perfectly on windows cmd, not detected on cygwin.

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev I see a gem and gem.bat but not gem.exe

Comment: sorry my bad. You should look for gem without an extension. And it seems you have it. Maybe try opening cygwin terminal and typing `ls /cygdrive/c/Ruby187/bin/gem`

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev I ran ls /cygdrive/c/Ruby187/bin/gem and it just echos /cygdrive/c/Ruby187/bin/gem. When I cd to /cygdrive/c/Ruby187/bin and then run gem I still see the same error I posted in my original question.

Comment: How did you install the stuff below your Ruby187 directory? Since the Cygwin mirrors usually don't carry such old program versions anymore, I wonder what you were doing here. If you don't find really old mirrors anywhere, I fear that you have to recompile your old Ruby from the sources, though it might be that they don't exist anymore. If you explain a bit, **why** you want to have this specific version, perhaps we can think about some workaround.